# UITableView section not showing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pdf-generation

In my application I am generating a Pdf from a UITableView by using [azu/ScrollViewToPDF](https://github.com/azu/ScrollViewToPDF/tree/master/ScrollViewToPDF). I succeeded in doing so but first section of the tableview is not showing properly as shown in the screen shot. Please help me to solve it. Thanks
[image: PDF From uitableview]

Comment: use heightForSectionInTableView properly

Comment: I used that property. Its 44.  if I decrease height, problem still there with small header.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanAnwar, What exactly the problem?

Comment: The problem is seen above. I am generating a Pdf from a tableview. As shown in the screen shot first header of the section is not showing at appropriate position

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 44;
    
}

Comment: I think it is about cells not about the header. Becareful if you hide some cells or changing their position in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

I just change the view controller settings from storyboard as.

[image: Settings].

Its under Attributes inspector. I just uncheck
Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars option.